# Is it okay to notch 1.5" on the bottom of beams in basement ceiling

Tags: structural, carpentry, natural-gas, basement-refinishing

I have a 100 year old city rowhouse and thinking to finish the basement.  I have cleared all the dangling electric cables and rerouted the water lines the attached to the ceiling beams. All I have left on the basement ceiling is the gas line that runs perpendicular to the basement ceiling beams. It is held with hangers against the beam but I was thinking to cut 1.5" notches on the bottom of the beams and fit the gas lines in.  The beams are a true 3"x8" and the notches would one side not in the middle.  If it one beam, I would think it is ok being 1.5" is less than 1/3 the size of the beam, but does cutting this notch on all the beams change things?  I am not sure I want to run CSST so I am looking to all options here.  Also, concerned notching all the beams will compromise the structure.  Any strong opinions against notching?  I want to clear the basement ceiling to make it appear more spacious and possibly put a ceiling and I only have 78" height.

Comment: Gas lines? More than 1? And are such large holes necessary? For _notching_ it's 1/6 beam height. For _holes_ 2" or more from top and bottom, it's 1/3 beam height. See https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.8. That's by today's book, though. What's the current condition of your floors? Is there much sagging already?

Comment: Have you built walls yet for this finished basement? You might route through them instead. Drilling the holes in uninstalled 2x4s sounds a lot easier than messing around over your head, too. That's if the walls aren't built yet.

Comment: CSST = Corrugated Stainless Steel Tubing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Notch **depth** is **1/6** of joist depth, maximum. **No notches at all** in the center 1/3 of the joist.

[image: notches and holes in joists]

*[Image source](https://i0.wp.com/boulderlibrary.net/img/1312/image1035.png?strip=all), no endorsement implied.*

Holes, of 1/3 joist depth or less in diameter may be placed at least 2" from the edges. The center of the joist is the least impact, structurally.

I would strongly suggest getting over whatever objection you have to CSST. You're messing with the gas line at all, you might as well end up with it at a modern standard of installation; And you can put it through holes.

Comment: I just noticed that the illustration's left hole is right next to the notch. Technically there's a busted constraint there. The constraint isn't shown in the IRC's illustration either (but the illustrator didn't explicitly break the constraint).